# How to represent query output in kibana to graph?

Tags: elasticsearch, graph, kibana

Kibana has dev tool. Where we can run the query and generate the output. How to visualise that query output in kibana dashboards ?

see 
[this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/dashboard-for-3-level-of-aggregation-in-kibana/191186)
 question for further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems a bit broad. Let me skip some details and give you a general idea.

In Kibana Dev Tools, you can run a query like below.

```
GET /bank/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_state": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "state.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you will see results in your Console like this :

[image]

In order to visualize it in your dashboard, first you need to create one visualization type in Visualize tab, and create your dashboard with it.

[image]

I made a pie chart, but not with the query above. But I use the same logic. You can see how I did it below.

[image]

Lastly, I created a dashboard and add the Visualization.

[image]

You can watch tutorial videos on how to create Visualization and Dashboard. When you run into another question as you learn, you can ask here anytime on Stack Overflow.

Comment: So if there is a complicated query in dev tool for example three level aggregation. How to represent that output of that query() in dashboard ?

Comment: @ManoharsinhRana   You can add sub-buckets. They can handle those. They have filter,  JSON input and many other ways to handle complex queries.

Comment: @ManoharsinhRana  Depeding on a visualization type, you can also add sub aggregation.  You can manipulate Y Axis and X Axis.